# VSS file check-in issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I am using Visual Source safe 2005, I am having problems with some files (.cs and .cshtml)
when I am  trying to check in them its giving me this error

```
the file cannot be checked in because it has different encoding and checked out multiple times
```

I am not using any encoding, these are normal Csharp and Razor view files.
I read on internet to install updates of VSS, I did this but still same problem.
This problem arising few days back,before that they were checkingin normally.

I am using windows 7 and VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

VSS2003 didn't recognized the [project].vspscc files as Utf-8, and treated them as Ansi; VS2010 recognized them as Utf-8, and doesn't allow you to checkin new versions when the file is multiple checked out. This is by design.

What you can do is undo checkout of the file in the VSS database and leave the file checked out only once. Then use VS to checkin the changes to your solution. If there aren't changes to this file, VSS2005 will not change automatically the file type in teh VSS database. You can open the file's Properties dialog and manually change the type "Ansi/Mbcs" into "Unicode (Utf-8)".